# Get data from textbox to pass to controller without refreshing page/submitting form in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Right now, on my page I have a button at the top of one of my views `<button type="button" id="show">Find Project</button>` that when pressed, renders a partial view (which is a table) at the bottom of the page. My layout is formatted as:

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <!--this is my navbar-->
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- TABLE WILL APPEAR HERE -->
    </div>
</body>
```

The javascript that makes the table appear is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#show").on("click", function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Projects/SearchTable',
            type: "GET"
        }).done(function(partialViewResult) {
            $(".wrapper").html(partialViewResult);
            $(".wrapper").css('display', 'block');
        });
    });
});
```

`/Projects/SearchTable` is the controller action that renders the partial view:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SearchTable()
{
    var states = GetAllStates();
    var model = new ProjectClearanceApp.Models.ProjectViewModel();

    model.States = GetSelectListItems(states);
    model.Projects = from m in db.Projects select m;

    return PartialView("~/Views/Projects/_ClearedProjects.cshtml", model);
}
```

The text boxes are dispersed throughout my main view, and all appear in the same format:

```
<div class="col-md-5 entry-field">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Project.FirstNamedInsured, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Project.FirstNamedInsured, new { @class = "form-control text-box single-line", maxlength=150 })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Project.FirstNamedInsured, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Except for two dropdowns that are formatted like so:

```
 <div class="col-md-3 address-info">
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Project.FirstNamedInsuredAddress.State, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "address-label" })
     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Project.FirstNamedInsuredAddress.State,
                           Model.States,
                           "--",
                           new { @class = "form-control address-entry" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Project.FirstNamedInsuredAddress.State, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

where Model.States is an enumerable to populate the drop down list with all of the states.

Is it possible to get the data from those textboxes and pass them as data/arguments to the controller for use in the partial view without submitting a form or refreshing the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the parameter like this:

```
        public ActionResult SearchTable(string firstNamedInsured)
        {
            //Use the parameter in the model or any where
            var states = GetAllStates();
            var model = new ProjectClearanceApp.Models.ProjectViewModel();

            model.States = GetSelectListItems(states);
            model.Projects = from m in db.Projects select m;

            return PartialView("~/Views/Projects/_ClearedProjects.cshtml", model);
        }
```

And javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#show").on("click", function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Projects/SearchTable?firstNamedInsured=' + $('#' + @Html.IdFor(m => m.Project.FirstNamedInsured)).val(),
                type: "GET"
            }).done(function (partialViewResult) {
                $(".wrapper").html(partialViewResult);
                $(".wrapper").css('display', 'block');
                });
        });
    });
```